# How to get value of textbox in jquery using name?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html element :

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="input-text ">
```

How can I get it's value using name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting all elements with `name="quantity"`

```
# HTML
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="input-text ">

#jquery
$('[name="quantity"]').val() // 1
```

For selecting all elements with `name=*`

```
# HTML
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="input-text ">
<input type="text" name="quality" value="2" class="input-text ">

#jquery
$('[name]').first().val() // 1
$('[name]').last().val() // 2
```

Comment: $('[name="quantity"]')[0].val() still give me an error : Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: @Taplar shoot, you're right. Updated my answer. The second example is just to show how to handle multiple elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').val()
```

Comment: It give's me this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null